# How to upgrade to Centos 7.3 to CentOS 7.5.x?

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I need to update my VM to CentOS 7.3 to 7.5. What is the standard procedure to upgrade the server?.

Answer (score 2):

`yum update` followed by a reboot ...

Have a current and tested backup ready, as usual.

Comment: That will update packages to the latest version available for the current version of the distribution, but it won't update to a later version of the distribution.

Comment: @kasperd: By default, the base repo config for yum points to the major version repo  (e.g. `7`), which is linked to the latest point release, so unless you manually point yum to a point release, it will automatically update to the newest release (this might be different for RHEL). Or are you talking about major releases, e.g. CentOS 8?

Comment: It's been a while since I have been using yum based distributions, so I guess it just means things have changed since then.

Comment: @kasperd: Yes, IIRC that changed between v6 and v7. We used to run Scientific Linux, where this behaviour was standard already on 6.